# Reference to type 'SqlConnection' claims it is defined in 'System.Data', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, system.data

I'm trying to build a .NET standard app in VS2017, but when trying to create a SQL Connection, I get the following error:

> Reference to type 'SqlConnection' claims it is defined in 'System.Data', but it could not be found

Note the error does not occur when instantiating the SqlConnection, it happens when I use it anywhere.  Below is my code:

[image]

Note I am targeting .NET Standard 2.0.  I have the System.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.Common Nuget packages installed.

Comment: 1. Try close / reopen Visual Studio. I know it sounds dumb, but it sometimes fixes "core" related issues. 2. Are you _only_ targeting `netstandard2.0` in your project file?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a simple repro that I can take a look at?

Comment: Yeah going along with @AlexGhiondea-MSFT ... If you create a new CLI project and try to reproduce the issue there using only the parts required to reproduce the issue it can help you figure out the issue on your own due to the simplification process, and if it doesn't it is a great way to share to ask for help using the simplified source code.

Comment: So I'll back up a bit and then try to build something simple.  What's the best way to share a project?  I'm a new contributor to stackoverflow so I need to work out some basics.

Comment: Just as a background though, I followed this tutorial **exactly** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.  I also followed this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVOFCFLJqkA.  I basically want to call an SSIS package when a file is added to my blob storage.  I found that the blob trigger works about 10% of the time for no apparent reason.  I build and run code and it works, then do nothing, build/run again and the trigger just doesn't fire.

Comment: So based on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148588/azure-function-version-2-0-app-blobtrigger-not-working/52724896#52724896, I tried adding Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, but that wouldn't compile because of an assembly mismatch unless I switched the Target Framework from .NET 4.7 to .NET Standard 2.0... but when I do that, I get the error above.

Comment: Are you able to run this locally at least? Have you tried doing the same code outside of Azure Functions?

Comment: yeah. I got similar issues running locally.  I actually just scrapped the whole project and am starting over.  It wasn't that much code anyway.  So far so good, but will hit a moment of truth shortly. Previously, everything worked individually outside of functions, it was really just a few lines of code calling the package... I ran into issues when trying to call SSIS **within** a function.  For future posts because I'm sure I will create more problems for myself, what's the best way to share a repro?

Comment: Aight, I literally copied and pasted everything from one project to another, but changed the project name and the function name and everything works OK now.  I'm chalking this up as something funky happening when adding/removing assemblies.  Must have been like a version mismatch or something?  No idea, but it works now.